# Do Eyebite effects continue if Concentration is lost?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

Eyebite allows you to:

> On each of your turns until the spell ends, you can use your action to target another creature

This seems to allow multiple creatures to be affected consecutively with different conditions and wasn't sure if those conditions are controlled by Concentration or if they are simply conditions given until the effect end triggers are given (woken up, saving throw passed, moved to an unseen position, etc.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## The effects end if concentration on *eyebite* is lost.

A creature who fails a save against *eyebite* is "affected by one of the following effects of your choice for the duration".

The duration of *eyebite* is "Concentration, up to 1 minute".

The fact that concentration appears in the duration field suggests that if concentration is lost, the duration of the spell is prematurely cut short.